# Cannot run GAE Test when gwt-dev dependency is removed (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/xml/XmlParser)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this error, some say it about the `httpcore` depdendency:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET
    at com.jayway.restassured.config.EncoderConfig.<init>(EncoderConfig.java:48)
    at com.jayway.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
    at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:423)
```

Yet however, running `mvn dependency:tree` gives

```
[INFO] +- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.3:compile
```

**Update:**

Apparently it is cause by the GWT dependency:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <version>${version.gwt}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
              <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

I already added exclusion and the error is gone, but removing `gwt-dev` makes the GAE test fail and throw this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/xml/XmlParser
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.getTopLevelNode(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:94)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:55)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:132)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart.isVMRuntime(KickStart.java:368)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart.<init>(KickStart.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart.main(KickStart.java:106)
```

Comment: If you show stacktrace than it would be helpful having the full stacktrace and not only exerpts..Furthermore a pom file would also be helpful.

Comment: @khmarbaise I found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make rest-assured not pick up GWT classes:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <version>${version.gwt}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

After having this order, the test works fine.